# How to get power reading on an Intel RAPL focal appliance?

Tags: bash, intel

I am working on a bash script to get power reading. The line of code **uj=$(cat /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0/energy_uj)** in the script produce the error: No such file or directory.

The CPU supports RAPL, but the path to the /intel/rapl in the /usr/ directory does not contain the energy_uj file. Does anyone know the path to get the power reading?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the find command:

```
find /sys/class/ -name '*energy_uj*' -ls
```

Comment: I have used the find options but there seem be no energy_uj file in the system. Powercap directory is empty. I am not sure if there any way to read the power under a different path?

Comment: Yea if its not there then not sure what to suggest, I don't have access to this hardware.